# Double arrows in the same direction in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-arrows

I would like to ask if anyone know how to define a "double arrow", two arrowhead on the same line next to each other in the same direction in tkz-euclide? I want the result to look like this:
[image: Double arrow]

For this illustration, I've used the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B}
\tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrow={Latex[blue] at 0.96}](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments[tkz arrow={Latex[blue] at 1}](A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is basically putting two arrows on top of each other, one at the very end and one at 96%. But this method wouldn't scale properly, and the black segment of the second arrow will stack on top of the arrowhead of the first one.

Can anyone help me please, thank you very much!